# Top Margin in QTextBrowser not working

Tags: css, pyqt

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
import sys

def main():    

    app = QApplication (sys.argv)
    browser = QTextBrowser()

    browser.setFixedSize(500,500)    
    browser.document().setDefaultStyleSheet('p{font-size:12px;} div{margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;}')
    ftext = '<div><h3><b></b></h3><p>akak</p><p>iuuo</p></div>'
    browser.setWindowTitle("QTextBrowser HTML File Input")
    browser.setHtml(ftext)
    browser.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
    browser.show()    

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to apply a top margin of 20px to the entire content but this code is not working. However a left margin of 20px is getting applied to the entire content.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using invalid css.  Try -

```
browser.document().setDefaultStyleSheet('p{font-size:12px;} div{margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;}')
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run for a start - you should remove the `self` references.

Comment: actually I copied it out of the app I was making so mistakenly it got remained.